# Mover div usando flechas

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo un div que quiero mover usando las flechas del teclado usando jquery, el problema es que solo lo doy movido a la derecha y se sale del section donde tiene que estar.
El html y css del ejercicio:

```html
<section id="square">
    <div id="hijo">
    </div>
</section>
```

```css
#square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

#square #hijo {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Mi jquery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(tecla){
    $('#hijo').css('position', 'relative');
    if (tecla.keyCode == 37) { 
        $('#hijo').animate({right: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
    }else if(tecla.keyCode == 38) { 
        $('#hijo').animate({up: "+=10px"}, 'fast'); 
    }else if(tecla.keyCode == 39){ 
        $('#hijo').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast'); 
    }else if(tecla.keyCode == 40){
        $('#hijo').animate({down: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Nota: no quiero modificar los archivos html y css si no hacer todo con jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un `switch` y utilizando el `event.which` para obtener la tecla que realizó el evento funciona correctamente, es cuestión de sumar y restar los pixeles hacia arriba y a la izquierda (`top`, `left`), te dejo el ejemplo:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(tecla){
//$('#hijo').css('position', 'relative');
    switch (tecla.which) {
    case 37:
        $('div').animate({
            left: '-=10px'
        }, 'fast'); //left arrow key
        break;
    case 38:
        $('div').animate({
            top: '-=10px'
        }, 'fast');
        break;
    case 39:
        $('div').animate({
            left: '+=10px'
        }, 'fast');
        break;
    case 40:
        $('div').animate({
            top: '+=10px'
        }, 'fast');
        break;
    }
});
```

```css
#square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

#square #hijo {
    background:#ccc;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="square">
    <div id="hijo">
    </div>
</section>
```

Te dejo también el ejemplo en tu versión de código con el mismo concepto del `top` y `left` que te comenté por si lo necesitas:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(tecla){
    $('#hijo').css('position', 'relative');
    if (tecla.keyCode == 37) { 
        $('#hijo').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    }else if(tecla.keyCode == 38) { 
        $('#hijo').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast'); 
    }else if(tecla.keyCode == 39){ 
        $('#hijo').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast'); 
    }else if(tecla.keyCode == 40){
        $('#hijo').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
    }
});
```

```css
#square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

#square #hijo {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="square">
    <div id="hijo">
    </div>
</section>
```

Te comento que en mi ejemplo dejé una línea comentada en el `JQuery`, ya que si observas en tu `css` le estás dando una posición `absolute` y luego en tu `JQuery` una posición `relative`. Espero te ayude esta solución. Saludos.

Comment: Al final estoy usando el switch, yo tiendo a usar mucho el if a pesar de que en casos como este un switch queda mejor. Ahora solo falta que el div no se salga del section que lo encierra.

Comment: @JPillado eso ya sería que juegues un poco con el código y lo intentes por ti mismo, si quedas atorado y tienes inconvenientes te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta. Si te ayudó mi respuesta agradecería que lo marques como correcto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

1. Tu listener de eventos del teclado en document pone a tu contenedor a competir con muchas otras cosas. Yo acotaría el problema declarando el listener sobre `#hijo`. Para que pueda escuchar eventos del teclado tiene que ser un elemento `focusable` así que lo convertí en un input. Ahí tú le daras estilo como mejor puedas.
2. La posición del elemento se determina por sus coordenadas X e Y, en este caso `left` y `top`. Definir propiedades contradictorias para `left` y `right` cuando las dimensiones del elemento son fijas no tiene mucho efecto.
3. dado que conoces las dimensiones del contenedor, y las del hijo, sabes que para que no se salga se debe cumplir que

   - top y left no pueden ser menores a cero
   - left no puede ser mayor que (ancho_contenedor - ancho_elemento)
   - top no puede ser mayor que (altura_contenedor - altura_elemento)

Yo guardaría el estado interno del elemento usando data attributes. Dependiendo de la tecla modifico el valor pero con la restricción que puse antes.

PD: usé `key` en vez de `keyCode`. Es más intuitivo pq son nombres.

```js
let hijo = $('#hijo'),
  square = $('#square'),
  coords = $('#coords'),
  squareWidth = square.width(),
  squareHeight = square.height(),
  pressed = $('#pressed');

hijo.keydown(function(keyboardEvent) {
  hijo.css('position', 'relative');
  keyboardEvent.preventDefault();
  keyboardEvent.stopPropagation();
  let {
    key
  } = keyboardEvent, {
    top,
    left
  } = hijo.data();

  pressed.text(`You pressed key ${key}`);
  if (key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    left = Math.max(0, left - 10);
  } else if (key == 'ArrowUp') {
    top = Math.max(0, top - 10);
  } else if (key == 'ArrowRight') {
    left = Math.min(squareWidth - 50, left + 10);
  } else if (key == 'ArrowDown') {
    top = Math.min(squareHeight - 50, top + 10);
  }
  hijo.animate({
    top,
    left
  }, 'fast').data({
    top,
    left
  });
  coords.text(`left:${left}, top:${top}`);
});
```

```css
#square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:160px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
}

#square #hijo {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#pressed {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
}

#coords {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 175px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pressed"></pre>

<section id="square">
  <input id="hijo" data-top="100" data-left="100" />

</section>
<pre id="coords"></pre>
```

Comment: los archivos html y css forman parte del ejercicio que estoy haciendo y por tanto estos NO PUEDO MODIFICARLOS, tienen que estar tal cual lo puse en la pregunta. lo que tengo que hacer el el jquery

Comment: Ya veo. Ojalá des con la solución